# Column grouping in ssrs report giving wrong results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Friends,
I need to calculate the various costs on the basis of month and year. Hence i used column wise grouping.
The thing is i am getting the total amount in each column and not the particular month's values.
The values taken directly from stored procedure are correct. But something is missing out in the expression i guess.
The expression goes like this:
=Sum(IIf(Fields!statusfld.Value = "Booking",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing),"DataSet1")

Any sort of guidance is appreciated. Thank you guys.

---

**UPDATE**

Here are image of report format

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show your format of report and the columns you are grouping on ?

Comment: i am a newbie. not able to post images. can u give me ur e mail id so i can forward it to u?

Comment: And also in place of `Nothing` use `0` in expression.

Comment: i tried replacing nothing with 0, but thats not an issue i guess

Comment: post it on the http://postimage.org/ and give me the URL i will update that in question and also make sure you explain what you want

Comment: http://postimg.org/gallery/1zpg2ixcu/2f9929c3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you want the total to be depend on the group of the month. That is total for each month, Atleast thats what I was understood. IF that's what you want then you are nearly there,Just make your expression scope to the groupname

```
  =Sum(IIf(Fields!statusfld.Value = "Booking",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing),"yourGroupname")
```

and that will give you the total for each column group.

Or you can try below approach --
To add totals for a column group
In the tablix data region row group area, right-click a cell in the column group area for which you want totals, then point to Add Total, and click Before or After.
A new column outside the current group is added to the data region, and then a default total is added for each numeric field in the column.

Comment: Thank you so much Coder of Code!

Comment: Hi, I have one more conflict. The expression above, if it already has a scope parameter based on Row Grouping how to add Column Grouping too? Or can we add multiple scope parameters for the same expression?

Comment: No you can not however you can use `IIF` to set the values when you want to show which value.

Comment: =Sum(IIf(Fields!category.Value = "DIRECT EXPENSES",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing), "statusfld") here "statusfld" is a row group scope parameter. I also want to add "Created_Month" which is my Column Grouping. So how would my expression be?

Comment: Can you post it as separate  question with more explanation. I am bit confused and also it is against the policy of Stack to discuss  new question in comments. I will give your answer there. Just post it with bit explanation and what exactly you need.